# mysql with ubuntu 13.10

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mysql-server and client after a wrong configuration. I tried uninstalling both but I get an error when I uninstall mysql-server:

```
    start: Job failed to start
    invoke-rc.d: inirscript mysql, action "start" failed
```

How do I delete it and reinstall it?

Comment: How are you trying to uninstall it? ```apt-get remove```?

Comment: yes, but it gives me that error!

Comment: @AlessandroDesantis grazie infinite!!!! ho risolto con il tuo link!! :)

Answer (score 0):

remove and purge mysql, and remove ALL setting in etc/msql

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server;
rm -r /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server;
```